# Is it possible that spark worker require more resource than the cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a stand alone cluster running on one node

```
root     23053     1  0 Apr01 ?        00:25:00 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip ES01 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
root     23182     1  0 Apr01 ?        00:19:30 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://ES01:7077
```

From the ps -ef command. We can see memory for master and worker is small **-xms1g -xmx1g -maxperm256m**

But when submit program to the cluster you can specify that the driver use 4G and worker use 8G. Why the program running on the cluster can acquire more memory than cluster?